# joomla module that references the users component and contact component

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am looking to create a module for registering a new user for my joomla! website. So basically, I want to create a form that ask for all types of information (first name, last name, username, pw, address, phone, etc... ) and store information like the username, password, and email, in my using the joomla! com_users component and the address, phone, first name, and last name using the joomla! com_contacts component. I don't understand how/if I am able to do this. I don't know how I can reference components in my module. I don't want to rewrite either component. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Community Builder (http://www.joomlapolis.org).  This is a great free Joomla component that adds all sorts of stuff to the user registration and management process, amongst other things.

Comment: This does not answer my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to use ChronoForms. It has a built in bridge to allow custom user registration forms that would get the info you collect in to com_users. You could then set up the form to also insert the collected data in to the com_contacts table after it handles the registration. No code hacking required.

Comment: This does not answer my questions. Thanks.

Comment: You want a registration form that writes to com_users and com_contacts correct?

Comment: That is correct, I think I am going to have to have to add to my own component to do this... I don't think there is any other way

Comment: My solution does exactly that. You create a Chronoform for registration, then you connect the form to com_contacts table with the DB connection. It will write the info to both tables.

Comment: ChromoForms seems intense! There are so many options. I will have to play around with it before I understand how it works. I don't like that you have to buy a license to use it though...

Comment: You dont have to buy a license. It is fully functional without the license and you can remove the link in the forms with CSS. You do have to leave the code there, but you can use display:none. If you like it and use it, then obviously it is nice to pay for a license.